# What effect does alcohol have?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I have come across the occasional can of beer/bottle of vodka. What will happen if I drink them? Can I get drunk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drinking an alcoholic drink will boosts your health above 100 - much like painkillers and hypostims, but with the added negative side effect of giving you blurred vision for a short period of time (the severity and duration of this effect vary depending on the drink).

The descriptions also imply that drinking them provides a "small increase in damage resistance", but I have no further information (such as duration or size of effect) and personally wonder if this is just indirectly referring to the fact you get a health boost.

If you examine the drink from your inventory it will tell you how much health it will add.

Comment: It also makes you more susceptible to damage.

Comment: @Arda do you know if this effect only lasts during the blurred vision or for longer? And do you know by how much?

Comment: I don't know by how much, but this is what the in-game text said.

Comment: @Arda, fair enough, I've edited something in. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I thought it made you *less* susceptible to damagae...

Comment: O_o make your minds up, I can't check directly myself until I'm home this evening.

Comment: @DMA Sorted it out yet?

Comment: @fred Sorry, I'd completely forgot about this last night >.< but if you read the description when examining a drink it will say whether it makes you more or less susceptible to damage.

Comment: @DMA I actually emptied my inventory of them a while back as they were taking up space, so I haven't got any to check at the moment!

Comment: I just picked up a bottle of vodka. "Beverage will imbue the drinker with a small increase in damage resistance."